# Android remove window background when it's not shown?

Tags: android

I was watching Romain Guy's [video(23:27)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UApv-ZMJ51g) about how to make android's UI fast and efficient and I discovered that the window background is always redrawn, even if it can't be seen. However, as it's an old video, I'd like to know if this problem has been addressed or not? Is it a good practice to always set a nobackground theme to activities that don't need it?